# Re-write code from Mathematica to Python. Solve function with matrices

Tags: python, sympy, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to rewrite one code from Mathematica to  Python. In Mathematica I have:

Solve[(K - w*M) . a == 0]

where K and M are square matrices, a = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}; and w will give the values in this case of 7 frequencies of the normal modes of vibrations of a system. Then, for each value of w, I get the relative positions of each x_i.

EDIT: I am inserting my full code:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

m=3.0
k=1.50


w,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7 = symbols("w,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7")

M = Matrix([[m,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,m,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,m,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,m,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,m,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,m,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,m]])
K = Matrix([[2*k,-k,0,0,0,0,0], [-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0,0],[0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0],[0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0],[0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0],[0,0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k],[0,0,0,0,0,-k,2*k]])
xn = Matrix([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7])

D1=K-w*M


print("omega squared")
A=solve(D1.det(), w)
print(A)

res =(np.array(A))**0.5


for i in range(7):
  omegan=float(res[i])
  wn=round(omegan**2,5)
  D1=K-wn*M
  print(D1*xn)
  print("\n** Positions x_i ", i+1, "for omega= ", np.sqrt(wn), " son; ",solve(D1*xn,xn))
```

I do get the same numerical values for w that I get in Mathematica, although for some numerical values in the matrices K and M, the calculation does not finish or after two minutes I do not get any response. For other numerical values, I do get the solution in less than 10 seconds.

Now, when I try to get the position of x_i for each numerical value of w with the following lines:

```
.
.
.
wn=omegan**2
D1=K-wn*M
solve(D1*xn,xn)
```

I get for all cases of wn
{x1: 0.0, x2: 0.0, x3: 0.0, x4: 0.0, x5: 0.0, x6: 0.0, x7: 0.0}

But with Mathematica I do get for example x1 -> 0.541196 x2, x3 -> 1.30656 x2, x4 -> 1.41421 x2, x5 -> 1.30656 x2, x6 -> x2, x7 -> 0.541196 x2.

I guess I am using a method not advisable in Python.

Comment: Can you please share your matrices K and M so that we can give you the best advice?

Comment: Note that sympy's `solve` tries to find exact symbolic solutions, while you seem to want one (of possibly many) numerical solution.  You might want to check out [sympy's documentation about different kinds of solvers](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

Comment: I could give a better answer if you showed complete code to make an example of the matrices K and M. It might seem obvious to you what is in those matrices but it is not obvious to me because many different things can be in a SymPy matrix. A short answer though is that rather than using `solve` you should probably use something like `nroots` because I think you are looking for approximate numerical roots of a polynomial. The other problem is most likely to do with solving an underdetermined linear system with inexact float coefficients but you need to show the matrices for a full answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have written my full code now in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the question is updated with complete code let's first see what those matrices look like:

```
In [2]: K
Out[2]: 
⎡3.0   -1.5   0     0     0     0     0  ⎤
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢-1.5  3.0   -1.5   0     0     0     0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0    -1.5  3.0   -1.5   0     0     0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0     0    -1.5  3.0   -1.5   0     0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0     0     0    -1.5  3.0   -1.5   0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0     0     0     0    -1.5  3.0   -1.5⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎣ 0     0     0     0     0    -1.5  3.0 ⎦

In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
⎡3.0   0    0    0    0    0    0 ⎤
⎢                                 ⎥
⎢ 0   3.0   0    0    0    0    0 ⎥
⎢                                 ⎥
⎢ 0    0   3.0   0    0    0    0 ⎥
⎢                                 ⎥
⎢ 0    0    0   3.0   0    0    0 ⎥
⎢                                 ⎥
⎢ 0    0    0    0   3.0   0    0 ⎥
⎢                                 ⎥
⎢ 0    0    0    0    0   3.0   0 ⎥
⎢                                 ⎥
⎣ 0    0    0    0    0    0   3.0⎦
```

It looks like you are trying to solve a generalised eigenvalue problem i.e. to find scalars `w_i^2` and nonzero vectors `x_i` such that

```
K x_i = w_i * M * x_i
```

SymPy does not have a dedicated solver for generalized eigenvalue problems like this but SciPy's eig function can do it for matrices of floating point numbers:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html

```
In [5]: from scipy.linalg import eig

In [11]: import numpy as np

In [12]: Kn = np.array(K, dtype=float)

In [13]: Mn = np.array(M, dtype=float)

In [14]: type(Kn), type(Mn)
Out[14]: (numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)

In [15]: Kn
Out[15]: 
array([[ 3. , -1.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [-1.5,  3. , -1.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. , -1.5,  3. , -1.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. , -1.5,  3. , -1.5,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , -1.5,  3. , -1.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. , -1.5,  3. , -1.5],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. , -1.5,  3. ]])

In [16]: Mn
Out[16]: 
array([[3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3.]])

In [17]: eig(Kn, Mn)
Out[17]: 
(array([0.07612047+0.j, 0.29289322+0.j, 0.61731657+0.j, 1.        +0.j,
        1.92387953+0.j, 1.70710678+0.j, 1.38268343+0.j]),
 array([[ 1.91341716e-01,  3.53553391e-01, -4.61939766e-01,
          5.00000000e-01, -1.91341716e-01,  3.53553391e-01,
          4.61939766e-01],
        [ 3.53553391e-01,  5.00000000e-01, -3.53553391e-01,
         -1.93816282e-16,  3.53553391e-01, -5.00000000e-01,
         -3.53553391e-01],
        [ 4.61939766e-01,  3.53553391e-01,  1.91341716e-01,
         -5.00000000e-01, -4.61939766e-01,  3.53553391e-01,
         -1.91341716e-01],
        [ 5.00000000e-01, -7.68527201e-16,  5.00000000e-01,
         -1.91221591e-16,  5.00000000e-01, -4.23414829e-16,
          5.00000000e-01],
        [ 4.61939766e-01, -3.53553391e-01,  1.91341716e-01,
          5.00000000e-01, -4.61939766e-01, -3.53553391e-01,
         -1.91341716e-01],
        [ 3.53553391e-01, -5.00000000e-01, -3.53553391e-01,
         -3.60198282e-16,  3.53553391e-01,  5.00000000e-01,
         -3.53553391e-01],
        [ 1.91341716e-01, -3.53553391e-01, -4.61939766e-01,
         -5.00000000e-01, -1.91341716e-01, -3.53553391e-01,
          4.61939766e-01]]))
```

Alternatively since the matrix M is invertible we can trivially turn this into an ordinary eigenvalue problem:

```
(M**-1 * K) x_i = w_i * x_i
```

Then we can do it with SymPy:

```
In [22]: evs = (M.inv() * K).eigenvects()

In [23]: print(evs[0])
(0.0761204674887132, 1, [Matrix([
[-0.191341716182545],
[-0.353553390593274],
[-0.461939766255643],
[              -0.5],
[-0.461939766255643],
[-0.353553390593274],
[-0.191341716182545]])])
```

That is just showing the first (`evs[0]`) eigenvector and eigenvalue and `1` there is the multiplicty of the eigenvalue.

The advantage of using SymPy rather than SciPy in this calculation would be if you wanted to compute the results exactly. To do that first turn your floats into rationals:

```
In [24]: Mr = M.applyfunc(nsimplify)

In [25]: Kr = K.applyfunc(nsimplify)

In [26]: Mr
Out[26]: 
⎡3  0  0  0  0  0  0⎤
⎢                   ⎥
⎢0  3  0  0  0  0  0⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎢0  0  3  0  0  0  0⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎢0  0  0  3  0  0  0⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎢0  0  0  0  3  0  0⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎢0  0  0  0  0  3  0⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎣0  0  0  0  0  0  3⎦

In [27]: Kr
Out[27]: 
⎡ 3    -3/2   0     0     0     0     0  ⎤
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢-3/2   3    -3/2   0     0     0     0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0    -3/2   3    -3/2   0     0     0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0     0    -3/2   3    -3/2   0     0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0     0     0    -3/2   3    -3/2   0  ⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢ 0     0     0     0    -3/2   3    -3/2⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎣ 0     0     0     0     0    -3/2   3  ⎦

In [28]: evs = (Mr.inv() * Kr).eigenvects()

In [29]: evs[0]
Out[29]: 
⎛      ⎡⎡-1⎤⎤⎞
⎜      ⎢⎢  ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢0 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢  ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢1 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢  ⎥⎥⎟
⎜1, 1, ⎢⎢0 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢  ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢-1⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢  ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢0 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ⎢⎢  ⎥⎥⎟
⎝      ⎣⎣1 ⎦⎦⎠

In [30]: evs[1]
Out[30]: 
⎛           ⎡⎡-1 ⎤⎤⎞
⎜           ⎢⎢   ⎥⎥⎟
⎜           ⎢⎢-√2⎥⎥⎟
⎜           ⎢⎢   ⎥⎥⎟
⎜           ⎢⎢-1 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜    √2     ⎢⎢   ⎥⎥⎟
⎜1 - ──, 1, ⎢⎢ 0 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜    2      ⎢⎢   ⎥⎥⎟
⎜           ⎢⎢ 1 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜           ⎢⎢   ⎥⎥⎟
⎜           ⎢⎢√2 ⎥⎥⎟
⎜           ⎢⎢   ⎥⎥⎟
⎝           ⎣⎣ 1 ⎦⎦⎠

In [31]: evs[2]
Out[31]: 
⎛                   ⎡⎡                               1                                ⎤⎤⎞
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                                                ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                             ________                           ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                           ╲╱ 2 - √2                            ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                                                ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                   2                            ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                   ⎛      ________⎞                             ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                   ⎜    ╲╱ 2 - √2 ⎟        ________             ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢            -5 + 4⋅⎜1 - ──────────⎟  + 4⋅╲╱ 2 - √2              ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                   ⎝        2     ⎠                             ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                                                ⎥⎥⎟
⎜      ________     ⎢⎢                        3                                      2⎥⎥⎟
⎜    ╲╱ 2 - √2      ⎢⎢        ⎛      ________⎞                       ⎛      ________⎞ ⎥⎥⎟
⎜1 - ──────────, 1, ⎢⎢        ⎜    ╲╱ 2 - √2 ⎟         ________      ⎜    ╲╱ 2 - √2 ⎟ ⎥⎥⎟
⎜        2          ⎢⎢-16 - 8⋅⎜1 - ──────────⎟  + 10⋅╲╱ 2 - √2  + 24⋅⎜1 - ──────────⎟ ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢        ⎝        2     ⎠                       ⎝        2     ⎠ ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                                                ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                   2                            ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                   ⎛      ________⎞                             ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                   ⎜    ╲╱ 2 - √2 ⎟        ________             ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢            -5 + 4⋅⎜1 - ──────────⎟  + 4⋅╲╱ 2 - √2              ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                   ⎝        2     ⎠                             ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                                                ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                             ________                           ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                           ╲╱ 2 - √2                            ⎥⎥⎟
⎜                   ⎢⎢                                                                ⎥⎥⎟
⎝                   ⎣⎣                               1                                ⎦⎦⎠
```

I won't show the rest because it is long but for completeness these are the approximate and exact eigenvalues as computed by SymPy:

```
In [34]: (M.inv() * K).eigenvals()
Out[34]: 
{0.0761204674887132: 1, 0.292893218813452: 1, 0.61731656763491: 1, 1.0: 1, 1.38268343236509: 1, 1.7 ↪

↪ 0710678118655: 1, 1.92387953251129: 1}

In [35]: (Mr.inv() * Kr).eigenvals()
Out[35]: 
⎧                         ________             ________                    ________             ___ ↪
⎪          √2            ╱ 1   √2             ╱ √2   1      √2            ╱ 1   √2             ╱ √2 ↪
⎨1: 1, 1 - ──: 1, 1 -   ╱  ─ - ── : 1, 1 -   ╱  ── + ─ : 1, ── + 1: 1,   ╱  ─ - ──  + 1: 1,   ╱  ── ↪
⎪          2          ╲╱   2   4           ╲╱   4    2      2          ╲╱   2   4           ╲╱   4  ↪
⎩                                                                                                   ↪

↪ _____       ⎫
↪    1        ⎪
↪  + ─  + 1: 1⎬
↪    2        ⎪
↪             ⎭
```

These are the eigenvalues as computed by SciPy:

```
In [36]: from scipy.linalg import eigvals

In [37]: eigvals(Kn, Mn)
Out[37]: 
array([0.07612047+0.j, 0.29289322+0.j, 0.61731657+0.j, 1.        +0.j,
       1.92387953+0.j, 1.70710678+0.j, 1.38268343+0.j])
```

Comment: Many thanks! Yes my interest was to find  the values of the scalars w_i^2 and nonzero vectors x_i because I would like to solve a system of coupled oscillators to get the frequency of each normal mode and its relative motion. This answer has been really helpful and I see that I need that I need to study more.